I am Dockerizing my Spring boot application and i am getting connection refusal errors
Here is my project
https://github.com/haseeb1988/spRegistration.git
// Creating network
docker network create -d bridge sp-sql-net 
// build images
docker build -t springboot_website .
//run container
docker run --network sp-sql-net --name springboot_mysql_container_rest -p 8080:8080 springboot_website
Problem:
I'm encountering an issue with my application. It works perfectly on my local machine, connecting to a MySQL database running in a Docker container. However, when I try to run my application inside a Docker container while using the same MySQL container, the application fails to start. I've tried both Docker commands and Docker Compose, but neither approach resolves the problem. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried both Docker commands and Docker Compose, but neither approach resolves the problem.  and i am expecting solution.

It looks like your application access the wrong MySQL port, your MySQL expose the 3307 port, but your application access the 3306 port

you can put the application log in your answer

Place your docker files and appllication configuration here. If you are running in a docker container don't use localhost to connect to your db container, instead use the container name (else it won't work).

I wanted to use port 3307 instead of 3306

both mysql and springboot_website have to run in the same network sp-sql-net .
Please provide mysql config in your app and the run command for mysql container.

Can you provide an example for mysql config, and both container are running on sp-sql-net network.
